# How to set text for EditText control when its inputType is number

Tags: android, android-edittext, settext

How to set text programmatically for EditText control when its inputType is number ?

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/WorkingHoursET"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/WorkingHoursTV"
    android:layout_below="@+id/WorkingHoursTV"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />


    EditText workedHours = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.WorkedHoursET);
    workedHours.setText(8); //this is not working
    workedHours.setText("8"); //neither this
```

Comment: i guess this is because you are passing wrong id WorkedHoursET insteaD OF WorkingHoursET

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
workedHours.setText("8", BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

---

If you check the docs for [`EditText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html), you'll find a `setText()` method. It takes in a `String` and a [`TextView.BufferType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.BufferType.html).

---

***NOTE :*** As Shailendra Singh Rajawat noted you might using wrong id of EditText. You should look into that too. That code should be

`EditText workedHours = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.WorkingHoursET);`